Method not allowed (405) when deployed on Vercel, but works locally
I've read many things about this but nothing works so I submit my case.
I try to call /api/contact with a POST Methos in my NextJS app.
Here is my API route:
export const runtime = 'edge';
export const methods = ['POST'];

import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import nodemailer from 'nodemailer';
import { LRUCache } from 'lru-cache';
...
export async function POST(request) {
  const { name, email, message } = await request.json();

  if (!name || !email || !message) {
    return NextResponse.json({ error: 'Please fill in all fields.' }, { status: 400 });
  }
...
  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
host: process.env.EMAIL_HOST,
port: process.env.EMAIL_PORT,
secure: process.env.EMAIL_SECURE === 'true',
auth: {
  user: process.env.EMAIL_USER,
  pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASS,
},
  });
...
    return NextResponse.json({ message: 'Message sent successfully.' }, { status: 200 });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error sending email:', error);
    return NextResponse.json({ error: 'Failed to send message.' }, { status: 500 });
  }
}

On the client side, I call it using fetch:
const res = await fetch(/api/contact, {
method: 'POST',
headers: {
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
},
body: JSON.stringify(formData),
});
The thing is that it works perfectly on localhost, but doesn't work when deployed on Vercel. How can I fix this? I've set up the environments variables.
